# Returning to the start of the Program

Tags: java

I'm a beginner at coding in Java and for my practice is a number guessing game.

I have at least 90% of the code right but my only problem is I do not know how I can make it keep the player input answers when instead of an integer, they input a letter or word.

Here's my code:

```java
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        Random number = new Random();
        int numberToGuess = number.nextInt(50);
        int numberOfTries = 0;
        int guess;

        boolean win = false;

        try {
            while (win == false) {

                System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 to 50:");
                guess = s.nextInt();
                numberOfTries++;

                if (guess == numberToGuess) {
                    win = true;
                } else if (guess < 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Number");
                } else if (guess >= 51) {
                    System.out.println("Number Exceeds Limit");
                } else if (guess < numberToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Too low; Guess again~");
                } else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
                    System.out.println("Too high; Guess again~");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("I think that is incorrect...");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("You Win!");
            System.out.println("The Number was:" + numberToGuess);
            System.out.println("It took you:" + numberOfTries + " tries");

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("I think something is wrong...");

        } finally {
            System.out.println("Please restart the Game if you wish to continue. Sorry for the Inconveniece");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: You might want to look into loops in Java (also Java is not JavaScript, they are different languages)

Comment: oops. sorry XP. I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

This will work until the user inputs an integer;

```
    boolean flag =true;
    while(flag){
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(new Scanner(System.in).next());
            flag=false;
        } catch(NumberFormatException ne) {
            System.out.print("That's not a whole number.\n");
        }
    }
```